# Making user reference field in Drupal 7?

Tags: entities

I have searched in Google with queries like "User reference drupal 7" or "User taxonomy vocabulary drupal" "user field drupal 7" "cck drupal 7" but I couldn't find any way to make a field that links for a user profile page... Do you know how to make this as a simple field can be done with CCK in Drupal 6? thanks.

Comment: are you trying to link to a nodes author? to a particular user? from where are you linking it? and what is the purpose - you need to provide more information

Comment: I just want to pick a user (preferably from autocomplete but select list would be great also), than I want to select it as I would select any taxonomy term and link to it's profile page...

Comment: from where? a node? a view? a custom module? a block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may look into [References](https://www.drupal.org/project/references) module

> This project provides D7 versions of the 'node_reference' and 'user_reference' field types, that were part of the CCK package in D6, at functional parity with the D6 counterparts.

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative to References is the [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) module. It can do user reference fields as well.